# How to create a python dataset from a local csv file?

Tags: python, csv, dataset

I have a `csv` file and am trying to create a dataset to use with `scikit-learn`.

Loaded these packages:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
```

I tried this:

```
sales = pd.read_csv("sales.csv") 
dataset = np.loadtxt(sales, delimiter=",")
```

And it gave me this error:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'endswith'

Please help! I am having no luck finding out how to create a dataset from a `csv` file.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

To clarify -- 
I'm try to follow this procedure http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ols.html, except I want to use my own data. I want to figure how to turn a csv into a python dataset, if that's even possible.

Comment: refer to this document https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html, might help to set your `dtype`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, sales is already the dataset. You are trying to pass a dataframe object in place of a filename. So you can either use sales directly as dataset since it will contain both features and labels or

```
dataset = np.loadtxt('sales.csv', delimiter=",")
```

Either way will work, if you have the correct format for the data.

Answer (score 1):

In your case sales is the DataFrame you are probably looking for. You can manipulate it for instance try printing sales.columns.

Comment: I don't really understand how that solves the problem. I did that, and it just prints the Index and dtype.